# Solve lifecycle difference measuring DOM nodes in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As I asked the other day to Dan Abramov [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/elrumordelaluz/status/1175037584164184064?s=20), I am trying to make some measuring of DOM nodes following [this example](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) in the official React docs.

Using a custom `hook` called `useOffset`, something like this:

```
function useOffset() {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(null);
  const ref = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setOffset({
        left: node.offsetLeft,
        width: node.offsetWidth,
        height: node.offsetHeight
      });
    }
  }, []);
  return [offset, ref];
}
```

And using in the desired *Component* like:

```
const [offset, ref] = useOffset();
```

But the problem I found is that the first render, the measurement is wrong due to not yet applied `styles`, FOUT and so on. The following renders will measure the right way.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/focused-fast-452bc) is the sandbox with the reproduction.

The first time the page loads or clicking the *reload* button of the *Codesandbox* browser, the red `outline` won't match with the `h1.title` but hidding and showing the elements again through the `button` which fires a re-render changing the *Component* `state`, the `outline` match perfectly the size (offset) of the element measured.

In the same [tweet](https://twitter.com/i/status/1175037584164184064) is also a video showing the wrong and desired behaviour.

**UPDATE** seems to be happen only in *Firefox* browser.

Comment: I thought it is related to the font loading, not the styles

Comment: Yes, because of this I cited FOUT. However, since the red `outline` has a so long width in the first render, I think it is due to `h1` is `display: block` by default so its width fills all the line. This value is changed by `css` in the demo.

Comment: Probably due to font-display: swap. Roboto fonts are "lazy" loaded. If you remove the CSS font-family definition you will notice it behaves correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Kunukn but in my case seems to persist the issue, look [here](https://pasteboard.co/Iz2FEmW.gif). However keep in mind the **update** that the issue seems to be only happen in _Firefox_.

Comment: Could you also render the width and height values? like in this example
https://codesandbox.io/s/roboto-font-eager-load-is13s

Note: I use React.useLayoutEffect to get around font loading ready-ness, might be inaccurate. We should wait until fonts says it is rendered onscreen.

Comment: Thanks again @Kunukn. At the end and thanks for the Brian Vaughn, we can confirm is a Firefox bug and not a React issue. Thanks anyway for the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opened a [react issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16885) and thanks to the input and interest of @Kunkn and [Brian Vaughn](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16885#issuecomment-535240326) is confirmed that the issue is related to specific Firefox browser behaviour, not related to *React*.